# Is it possible to display an xml code on a page in ReactJS?

Tags: html, xml, reactjs

Say I have this xml code and I want to display it on my page:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> <rss version=\"2.0\">  
<channel> 
      <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>   
<link>https://www.w3schools.com</link> 
      <description>Free web building tutorials</description>   
<item>     
<title>RSS 
    Tutorial</title>     
<link>https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp</link>
         <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>   </item> </channel>  </rss>
```

I tried doing this, but the output is not what I want:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.body }} />
```

The output is like this:

https://www.w3schools.com Free web building tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp New RSS tutorial on W3Schools

Which is not what I want. I want it to display the rss feed on my page without redirecting me, how can I do that? (Btw, the body is reading perfectly fine, so the problem is not from the body)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the XML source code, then just output it as you would any other text:

```
<div>
    { this.state.body }
</div>
```

If you want to do sensible formatting, then you'll need to actually parse the XML and extract the data you care about from it. (There are JavaScript RSS parsers out there, you might want to look on NPM for a library you can use to do the heavy lifting for you).

Comment: The first solution you suggested only displays the body with no content. Will the parsers display the content as from the original page? I don't think it will other than just some information in JSon right?